# Run Docker Image of DAPR Azure Function with DaprTopicTrigger not working

Tags: c#, azure, docker, azure-functions, dapr

I have created a Azure Function using DAPR DaprTopicTrigger when I am running the code locally it works fine. I created an Docker image and when I am trying to run using the dapr run command I am getting error "unknown flag: --image".

Function code

```
namespace TestFuncApp
{
public static class TestTrigger
{
    [FunctionName("TestTrigger")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [DaprTopicTrigger("testQueue", Topic = "testQueue")] CloudEvent @triggerData,
        [DaprPublish(PubSubName = "testQueue", Topic = "testQueue")] IAsyncCollector<DaprPubSubEvent> pubEvent,
        ILogger log)
    {
        var strTest =@triggerData.Data.ToString();
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request." + strTest);
        await pubEvent.AddAsync(new DaprPubSubEvent("Test Event at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")));
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); 
    }
}
}
```

The pubsub component file

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: testQueue
spec:
  type: pubsub.redis
  version: v1
metadata:
- name: redisHost
  value: localhost:6379
- name: redisPassword
  value: ""
```

Here is the dockerfile code

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS installer-env

COPY . /src/dotnet-function-app
RUN cd /src/dotnet-function-app && \
mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \
dotnet publish *.csproj --output /home/site/wwwroot

# To enable ssh & remote debugging on app service change the base image to the one below
# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:4-appservice
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:4
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY --from=installer-env ["/home/site/wwwroot", "/home/site/wwwroot"]
```

The command I use to run and test code locally is

```
dapr run --app-id testqueue -p 3001 -H 3503 --components-path ./components/  -- func host start
```

But when I create image using docker build and run using below command I am getting error .

```
dapr run --app-id testqueue -p 3001 -H 3503 --components-path ./components/  --image testImage -- func host start
```

Please suggest if anybody have successfully run Azure function with DAPR in a docker image.

Comment: Did you build your docker image?

Comment: Yes I built the image.